# Trying to achieve some kind of scrollable container with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I have `<div>` with some dynamic content inside - sometimes it is table, sometimes it is text. I'm trying to setup some kind of container which would be scrollable on y-axis if its contents are too big for the screen.

Some googling suggests that its simple to do if you hardcode `height` of the `div`, but what should I do if I want to avoid specifying exact pixel sizes anywhere?

From what I understand, I'll have to calculate remaining vertical visible screen space first, then set it as div `height`. This seems like a fairly common task, yet I can't find any components(don't care if they are `jquery` dependent or not) that would accomplish this.

Any suggestions? Already existing solution(plugin, library, etc) is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like the container height to start scrolling when it matches the viewport height, you can just give it `height` or `max-height` equal to `100vh` (100% viewport height).

In case there are other elements outside of the container and it shouldn't take the full screen height you can use `calc()` to limit it:

```
.container { max-height: calc(100vh - 100px); }
```